# Looking up an AVRO file and passing the content to a Web Activity in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory, avro

I am struggling to correctly pass specific contents of an .AVRO file, to a web activity in Azure Data Factory pipeline.

I have a lookup activity, that looks up the .AVRO file, I then store the output.value of that lookup, using a set variable activity;

```
@activity('Lookup Avro File').output.value
```

This variable output is as follows;

```
{
    "name": "variable1",
    "value": [
        {
            "Type": "Email",
            "Value": "exmaple1@gmail.com",
            "Timestamp": "2023-12-20 15:54:20.SSS",
            "IsAllowed": true
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to pass that content held in value, to a web activity, whereby the body of the request is formatted like so;

```
{
   "Key":"MarketingPreferences",
   "Value":[
      {
         "Type":"Email",
         "Value":"exmaple1@gmail.com",
         "Timestamp":"2023-12-20 15:54:20.SSS",
         "IsAllowed":true
      }
   ]
}
```

How can I achieve that within a Web Activity, this is what I have attempted in the body:

```
{
    "Key": "MarketingPreferences",
    "Value": @{variables('variable1')}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above expression which you have tried will work as expected.

[image]

If you see the input of the body, it will show the result of the expression as string.

[image]

But you need to check your target. Here, for sample, I have sent the above data to a blob JSON file using web activity and you can see it uploaded successfully with same body expression.

[image]